# TypeScript - Puppeteer library error: "Cannot find name 'Element'"

Tags: typescript, puppeteer

I have included `puppeteer-core` as a dependency in my TypeScript project, and am using Visual Studio 2019. When I try to build the project, I get this error below (as shown by the red squiggly underline under `Element`):

[image]

> error TS2304: Build:Cannot find name 'Element'

How can I resolve this please?

Comment: is this a ReactJS project?

Comment: This is a blank NodeJS console application, created with Visual Studio.

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Adding `dom` to my `tsconfig.json`'s [array of libraries](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) fixed the issue by compiling in the [DOM library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/DOM):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```